# Ubuntu + Git + Netbeans 7 - Do we need to install Git on OS?

Tags: git, netbeans, ubuntu

The dev version of Netbeans has Git support. This is great. I'm not sure however, what does this mean, in the following sense:

Should we install some sort of git commands into Ubuntu anyway, OR, the Git IDE plugins normally deal with this?

If this is very specific we can generalize a little, on other IDE's, on any subversion system, when we have a versioning control plugin on it, does it means that we DON'T need to configure it on our OS ?

Thanks a lot,

MEM

Comment: Just try it without /usr/bin/git installed. Either git is bundled (maybe with jgit; eclipse's egit does that) or you'll be prompted to install it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally, what this means is, you would need to install git on the server.

From there, the IDE would be able to keep its own configuration and use the git installation on the OS.  Sometimes, but not always, IDE's will use their own, known working version of git that they know work with their IDE.

So, don't install git yet, and try to use the program, and if it has problems interfacing with git, and you get suspecting errors of git not being found or something of that nature, you probably need to install on the OS.

Comment: I have no git server. I will use github or any repository service host around the web. Do you believe that the local repository folder should be the same as the IDE project one? Or should we have them on a different place? Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: @MEM: Your git server will be github, etc, however, you would still need git on the OS side.  git will interface with any repository, but you MUST have the git binaries on the OS weather you install it or the IDE has a custom installation.  What I usually do is have a "Projects" folder and each project in its own folder within the project folder (workspace). So each "project name" (which is in the project folder), is a git repository, which is my working directory.  So, `IDE -> Projects -> project1` or `IDE -> Projects -> project2`